# Probability of n independent and exponentially distributed racers finishing in ascending order

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Consider a race of $n$ runners whose finishing times are i.i.d and drawn from an exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. Assign a number id to each racer. What is the probability that the racers finish in ascending order?

My guess would be $\frac{1}{n!}$, since, by symmetry, all finishing orders are supposed to be of equal probability. However, I don't seem to be able to formally prove this...
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your $\frac{1}{n!}$ symmetry/exchangeability argument is correct and works for any continuous distribution where the probability of ties is $0$.  You could attempt a conditional probability argument, but it would not be more convincing.

Comment: Thanks Henry for the quick reply.
Maybe you can help me a follow-up.
How would I go about calculating the same probability given that the last racer started late (say at time $t_0$)?

Comment: You could approach that adjusted question by considering the probability that $k$ runners had not finished by time $t_0$, use the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, and your factorial answer, and sum over $k$